# How to stop wordpress converting html that is inside <pre><code>here</code></pre>

Tags: wordpress

I'm posting a front end tutorial which includes an html section. I've disabled the visual editor and am using prismjs for code highlighting which works great.

However when it comes to the html wordpress is converting it, not showing it raw.

Is there a way around this? I've tried a couple of plugins, including Raw HTML, but no joy...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My way round this is to blog in markdown. It converts the < > and things into html characters. Plus it's a super nice way to write anyway.

Answer (score 2):

This is covered [right in the Codex](https://codex.wordpress.org/Writing_Code_in_Your_Posts).

`<pre>` and `<code>` only change the appearance of code blocks; they don't prevent code from being interpreted as HTML.

In short, you need to encode all HTML entities, either manually or by running your code blocks through a custom shortcode or function.

Answer (score 1):

You have an icon in your visual editor which enables you to write code in your posts.

In addition, you could install one plugin (there are a lot) to show your code with colors and other features to make your code easier to read.

I hope this answer will help you.